# Check if url returns 200 using bash

Tags: bash

I need to check if the remote file exists based on the url response by doing:

```
curl -u myself:XXXXXX -Is https://mylink/path/to/file | head -1
```

What can give something like these:

```
'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
'
```

or

```
'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
'
```

Now, I want to extract the http status code like `200` from the resulting string above and assign the number to a variable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-o` option to send the headers to `/dev/null`, and use the `-w` option to output *only* the status.

```
$ curl -o /dev/null -u myself:XXXXXX -Isw '%{http_code}\n' https://mylink/path/to/file
200
$
```

If you intended to capture the status to a variable, you can omit the newline from the format.

```
$ status=$(curl ... -o /dev/null -Isw '%{http_code}' ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep:

```
curl -u myself:XXXXXX -Is https://mylink/path/to/file | head -1 | grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and simple:

```
curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://google.com
```